# htaccess redirecting files with multiple dots in filename

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a wordpress blog on my server and I wanted to keep some files on subdomain. The thing is that every file which contains multiple dots (example: com.mydomainname.pl.MoveLockScreentoUnlock.deb), when I try to download it its redirecting me to main page of my wordpress. I want to be able to download all files with deb extesnion but I cant.

What shoul I change in my htaccess?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

---

Update:
Yes file is on the server. Maybe its a problem with suExec? Any other ideas? Its redirecting only if I'm trying to download a file with multiple dots in filename. Im putting full path to this file.

You can check the problem here:
http://mojei.pl/cydia/beta/debs/

You can download file: **pl.MoveLockScreentoUnlock.deb**
but you cant download: **com.mojei.pl.mObileAlb.deb**

**-- Response to Eliasdx**

Yes file is on the server. Maybe its a problem with suExec? Any other ideas? Its redirecting only if I'm trying to download a file with multiple dots in filename. Im putting full path to this file.

You can check the problem here:
http://mojei.pl/cydia/beta/debs/

You can download file: **pl.MoveLockScreentoUnlock.deb**
but you cant download: **com.mojei.pl.mObileAlb.deb**

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have fixed it with my plugin

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fix-multiple-redirects/

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.deb$
```

Edit:

However the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` should already do the trick. It should not redirect if the file exists. Are you sure the file is there?